# Для чего нужны in и out в функции копирования памяти?

Tags: функции, память, документация

Нашёл пример, где функция копирования содержимого из одной области памяти в другую принимает три аргумента: исходную область памяти (`param[out]`), целевую (`param[in]`) и количество байт для копирования (`param[in]`).

Не совсем понимаю разницу между in и out. Для чего нужны эти значения?

Comment: Вы не путаете ничего? По идее память, в которую копируют, должна быть OUT...

Comment: Владимир Мартьянов, нашёл здесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/252101/. Да, там целевая - это in.

Comment: ИМХО там автор попутал: "dest Исходная...", "Копирует содержимое из исходной", но dest судя по названию - целевая область, приемник копируемых данных. Ниже в ответе вам развернули :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, не IMHO, а **абсолютно точно** перепутаны.

Comment: @Arden обратите внимание, тот пост был исправлен

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так как Вы видимо специально не указали, где именно взяли эту документацию, то мой ответ может чуточку отличаться от того, что будет написано там, но идеологически он будет близок.

У "классических функций" все аргументы "in" - то есть входящие. На них накладывается одно требование - они должны быть доступны на чтение и если вдруг функция внутри их поменяет, то внешний код об этом не узнает. Обычно такие аргументы могут передаваться непосредственно (например, просто число), так и переменной/выражением.

Но иногда внутрь функции нужно передать аргумент, который можно изменить. Да, классические функции обычно возвращают результат, но иногда этого бывает недостаточно. В этом случае нужны как раз "out". Классический пример - передача указателя на переменную. Функция внутри себя может записать туда значение и вызывающий код его "увидит".

Более того, если in параметр должен содержать осмысленное значение (кроме случая, если он не используется внутри), то out вполне может быть не инициализированным.

Некоторые компиляторы по умолчанию считают параметры как in, а для out нужно явно указать (паскаль, делфи, C#). Более того, компилятор даже может проверить, а возвращается ли значение. Конечно, всегда есть обходные пути и можно обмануть компилятор:).

Посмотрим на классический вид функции копирования памяти

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

изначально здесь не совсем понятно что к чему (для начинающих программистов). Но если сказать, что destination это out, a source и num in, то ситуация немного стает понятнее (хотя сами имена как бы и так намекают). В этом случае как бы есть гарантия, что то, что передано по source не будет изменятся (там кстати const ещё раз намекает). А то что будет по destination адресу храниться - поменяется - там же out.

Подсумируем. В большинстве случаев (если это с/с++, ассемблер), in/out это просто соглашения (и таких ключевых слов нет). В других языках компилятор может немного проверить (паскаль, C# и в них даже есть такие слова). Вполне возможно, что есть языки программирования, которые содержат более строгие правила и вполне даже откажутся компилировать, если декларация расходиться с кодом. В компиляторе gcc есть специальные ключевые слова (это уже расширения), которые частично это также реализовывают. Плюс, компилятор может поверить Вам и сделать оптимизацию.

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение.

Comment: Можно еще `in-out` добавить, тоже бывают (очевидный пример -- сортировка)

Comment: да, но in-out - это тот же out, который требует инициализацию.

Comment: Возможно. А Вы сами в такой ситуации (сортируемый массив) что напишите? (Я (если формально требуется) напишу in-out)

Comment: in-out могут быть разные. поэтому, скорее всего, подобные параметры я распишу отдельно.